# Stripe Apple Pay got error "You did not provide an API key"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, stripe-payments, applepay

I am trying to implement Apple Pay with stripe using this link:
https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay

II implemented all steps respectively, but I face the following error:

```
StripeCore.StripeError.apiError(StripeCore.StripeAPIError(type: StripeCore.StripeAPIError.ErrorType.invalidRequestError, code: nil, docUrl: nil, message: Optional("You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. \'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY\'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."), param: nil, statusCode: Optional(401), _allResponseFieldsStorage: Optional(2 fields)))
```

here is the code that I have:

```swift
func payWithApplePay(reservation: Reservation) {
        guard let merchantIdentifier = self.merchantIdentifier else {
            fatalError("merchant identifier must be defined!")
        }
        
        clientSecrets = reservation.clientSecret
        
        let pr = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantIdentifier, country: "AE", currency: "AED")
        
        pr.requiredBillingContactFields = []
        pr.requiredShippingContactFields = []
        pr.shippingMethods = []
        pr.paymentSummaryItems = reservation.payment?.message?.map{ object in
            return PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: object.message ?? "Unknown", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "100"))
        } ?? []
        
        if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: pr, delegate: self) {
            applePayContext.presentApplePay()
        } else {
            fatalError("applepay context is nil!")
        }
        
    }
```

and the extension is:

```
extension PaymentViewModel: STPApplePayContextDelegate {
    func applePayContext(_ context: StripeApplePay.STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: StripePayments.STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping StripeApplePay.STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
      
        guard let clientSecret = clientSecrets.first else {
            print("There is no client secret!")
            completion(nil, NSError())
            return
        }
        print("client secret: \(clientSecret)")
        completion(clientSecret, nil)
    }
    
    func applePayContext(_ context: StripeApplePay.STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: StripePayments.STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
        //
        print("Error is : \(error)")
        switch status {
        case .success:
            // Payment succeeded, show a receipt view
            break
        case .error:
            // Payment failed, show the error
            break
        case .userCancellation:
            // User canceled the payment
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

but apparently the following function (in the extension) isn't executed (but I don't have any idea why it isn't?)

```
func applePayContext(_ context: StripeApplePay.STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: StripePayments.STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping StripeApplePay.STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
    
        guard let clientSecret = clientSecrets.first else {
            print("There is no client secret!")
            completion(nil, NSError())
            return
        }
        print("client secret: \(clientSecret)")
        completion(clientSecret, nil)
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what part of your code specifically is triggering that error? Did you also make sure to configure your publishable key https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#setup?

Comment: @karbi Thank you for your comment, it was exactly my fault that I forgot to add the publishable key to the transaction.